# fire useEffect on page loaded - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I work with react-admin (so my content is feteched from my API) and I created a button to minimize the text lenght, so that my table cells does not have a big height, and keep an easy to read table.

[image: not minimized text]

[image: minimized text]

Here is my code :

```
const [isMinimized, setIsMinimized] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {

        if (isMinimized) {
            // reduce texts size
            const spans = document.getElementsByClassName("MuiTypography-body2");
            const spansList = [...spans];
            for (const span of spansList) {
                if (span.textContent.length > 20) {
                    span.textContent = span.textContent.substring(0, 20) + "..."
                }
            }
        }

    }, [isMinimized]);
```

I trigger this function with a state that change when I click on my button "minimize content".

Now, I'd like to apply this function but when the page is mounted. Not on click event. I want to get rid of the button.

So I tried to set my isMinimized state to true, and apply my useEffect when it is true but on first page load, it does not work.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

PS : It does not work on page load, but if I go to another component, and come back, it works. So I'd like to apply my useEffect on first page load

Comment: you can add empty dependency array to useEffect to work on componentDidMount, if not console the value of spans, may be the elements are not rendered to DOM

Comment: @Naveen not true, `useEffect` hooks that contain dependencies still run when the component has mounted

Comment: @Naveen, yes I think my useEffect apply before the span content arrives from api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to minimize the cells on page load and get rid of the minimize button all together.

You can achieve this by simply passing an empty array to the dependency array like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {

  // reduce texts size
  const spans = document.getElementsByClassName("MuiTypography-body2");
  const spansList = [...spans];
  for (const span of spansList) {
    if (span.textContent.length > 20) {
      span.textContent = span.textContent.substring(0, 20) + "..."
    }
  }

}, []);
```

Passing an empty dependency array will let the function passed to `useEffect` run on the first render, hence eliminating the need for a state variable.

Alternatively, an easier method to achieve the same result would be to use the CSS Text Overflow `ellipsis` property to truncate strings while still preserving content like so:

```css
.truncate {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

More info on this [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. This was my first attempt but (maybe because of react-admin ?) it does not work. it only put my text on one line. So it is not height the problem, but width now haha

Comment: I finaly manage to make css work by overpassing some react-admin classes :) thanks !!

Comment: While the react code you've given might have solved the issue(looks like it did not), your understanding is incorrect. useEffect will run on mount even if the dependency list is not empty.

Comment: @nullptr I know that. Problem with using the state variable isMinimized in the hook there is that when it fires on render, isMinimized is going to be false, so it's not going to run that piece of code. I was hoping that having it run without that if condition might have solved the problem.